# jQuery scrollLeft not working on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form which a user can use 'prev' and 'next' buttons to navigate through the form.
Here is my code and jQuery:

```
<div id="slideWrapParq">
    <div id="slide1">           
        <div class="parqInfo">Regular physical activity is fun and healthy, and increasingly more people are starting to become more active every day. Being more active is very safe for most people. However, some people should check with their doctor before they start becoming much more physically active. Completion of this questionnaire is a first step when planning to increase the amount of physical activity in your life.</div>
        <div class="parqWrapInner">
            <form action="/" method="post" id="parqForm">
                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q1: </span>Has a Doctor / Medical Professional ever diagnosed you with a heart condition and indicated you should restrict your physical activity?</div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q2: </span>When you perform physical activity, do you feel pain in your chest? </div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q3: </span>When you were not engaging in physical activity, have you experienced chest pain in the past month? </div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q4: </span>Do you ever faint or get dizzy and lose your balance? </div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q5: </span>Do you have an injury or orthopaedic condition (such as a back, hip, or knee problem) that may worsen due to a change in your physical activity?</div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q6: </span>Do you have high blood pressure or a heart condition in which a Doctor / Medical Professional is currently prescribing a medication?</div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q6" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q6" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q7: </span>Are you pregnant? </div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q7" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q7" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q8: </span>Do you have insulin dependent diabetes? </div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q8" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q8" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                #<div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q9: </span>Are you 69 years of age or older and not used to being very active?</div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q9" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q9" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="parqRow">
                    <div class="parqCell"><span class="red">Q10: </span>Do you know of any other reason you should not exercise or increase your physical activity? </div>
                    <div class="parqCell">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" name="Q10" value="yes">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" name="Q10" value="no">
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="MEMBERGUID" id="MEMBERGUID" value="0399589c-66bd-e211-8911-00155d007722" />
            </form>
            <p class="point"><span class="red">* </span>If you honestly answered no to all questions you can be reasonably certain you can safely increase your level of physical activity gradually.</p>
            <p class="point"><span class="red">* </span>If your health changes so you then answer yes to any of the above questions, seek guidance from a Doctor.</p>
            <p class="point"><span class="red">* </span>If you health changes so that you then answer yes to any of the above questions, tell your Doctor / medical professional. Ask whether you should change your physical activity plan.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slideButtons">
            <a href="/~fitspace/index.php/membership?view=memberForm1" class="signupFormPrev">Prev</a> 
            <a href="#" class="signupFormNext">Next</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2">
        sgfskgposgkporskgrspogk
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.signupFormNext').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#slideWrapParq').animate({scrollLeft: "+=770"}, 500, "swing");
});
```

and the CSS:

```
#parqWrapInner {
  min-height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 2310px;
}
#parqWrapper div#slide1, #parqWrapper div#slide2, #parqWrapper div#slide3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  width: 770px;
}
```

The slide divs are positioned next to each other in the `#slideWrapParq` div so when the button is clicked this div is supposed to slideLeft in order to bring the next slide in. For some reason this is not working and I have been trying to sort it the last few hours!
It is definitely the right selector as well as I have tested other jQuery events on it.
Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. Your PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: You have two elements with the ID `slideWrapParq` - jQuery doesn't like that.

Comment: Hi,You were correct but unfortunately that was some bad editing in my question. There is only actually one instance of this ID and it still doesn't work

Comment: why don't you create a simple simulation of your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Ok Ikind of have a Fiddle of what I want it to do. http://jsfiddle.net/eMQ7G/1/.

Comment: When I click on the 'next' button I want the div containing the slide divs to move to the left by 770px, therefore bringing in the next slide.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing your jsfiddle, I noticed you didn't have any of your containers `overflow` set to scroll, which makes me think you have a misunderstanding about `scrollLeft` and how it works.

With that assumption in mind, I think you're most likely looking for a sliding effect which can easily be done without scrollable containers. Your jsfiddle was quite chaotic so I created a very simple slider example using both `scrollLeft` and `left`:

### scrollLeft | [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9JPy/4/)

```
$('.next').on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollLeft: '+=600'
        }, 600);
});

$('.prev').on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#content").animate({
        scrollLeft: '-=600'
        }, 600);
});
```

### left (slide-like) | [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9JPy/1/)

```
$('.next').on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#contentWrapper").animate({
        left: '-=600'
        }, 600);
});

$('.prev').on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#contentWrapper").animate({
        left: '+=600'
        }, 600);
});
```

I made some notes on the CSS to help you better understand the `scrollLeft` animation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
animate({scrollLeft: "+=770"}
```

Comment: Hi, thaks for you answer. These were not supposed to be in there I was just experimenting. It doesn't work still without the 'px' either

Comment: I see, well it was just a quick guess.